# nature of the spread parameter in the Levy distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

The reflected Levy distribution is given by
$$
p(x):=
\left\{
\begin{array}{lcl}
\sqrt{\frac{\sigma}{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{\sigma}{2(\mu-x)}}\cdot (\mu-x)^{-\frac{3}{2}} &,& \text{if}\; x\leq\mu\\
0 &,& \text{if}\; x>\mu
\end{array}
\right.
$$
where $\mu>0$ and $\sigma>0$ are the location and the spread parameters, respectively. Is the spread parameter, $\sigma$, identical to the standard deviation of this distribution? If it is not, what is the standard deviation of $p$?

Comment: The variance of the distribution itself is un-defined, i.e. the integral does not converge.

Comment: The scale parameter can be interpreted in terms of hitting times of a (standard) Brownian motion.

Comment: Does this mean that all the moments and cumulants of this distribution don't exist as well? Can you say more about this interpretation that you alluded to, i.e. hitting times of a standard Brownian motion.

Comment: The first moment also diverges. Regarding the first-passage-time/hitting time, take a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-hitting-time_model . It is written by a physicist it seems, but still is detailed enough.

Comment: I have computed the variance and the first moment of p(x), and I have closed-form expressions for these statistical measures. They both involve the complementary error function. I don't understand why it is said here that they don't exist. Any comments are appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide your computation in this post?

Comment: I think that when people say that the first moment and the variance don't exist, they are referring to the regular (i.e. not reflected)  Levy distribution. It seems to me that the reflected version of this distribution behaves differently. My closed form calculations are quite long, many pages - I don't believe I made a mistake anywhere in the calculations.

Comment: What do you mean by the reflected Levy distribution?

Comment: The Levy distribution defined on the negative half-line.